# VbScript to save a current open Word document

Tags: vbscript

hi
I want vbscript to save a current open Word document, I am using the code:

```
 Dim objWord As Object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
    objDoc.Save
```

but it is opening a new word document and then asking me to save.

My requirement is i have created a menu button on click of it if the doc is already saved at a location it should save the changes made or if it is not it should ask me the path and save it there

Thanks
Creator

Comment: If you have a new document and you try to save for the first time, actually Word asks you for the path, so why are you trying to rebuild functionality which is already there?

Answer (score 0):

objWord.Documents.Add means creating a new document.

Try:
objDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code:

```
Dim activeDoc
Set activeDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument
activeDoc.Save
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using VBScript, use a VBA macro, which will be started in-process. Using the "`Application`" object will grant you access to the current Word instance, and `ActiveDocument` (which is short for `Application.ActiveDocument`) will give you access to the current document.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same thing and this is what I used:

```
' Create the File System Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Check for directory folder.
If objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objWord.Visible = True

        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(objFile.Path)
        objDoc.SaveAs objFSO.BuildPath(strDirectory, objFSO.GetFileName(objFile.Path))
        objDoc.Close
etc...
```

You will have to fill in the rest and init the variables, but this is working code.

HTH,

James