# How can I save a Word document using VB script?

Tags: vbscript, save, cpu-word

I need to strip all custom properties from a set of Word documents regularly.

I can open a Word document using VB script and go through the custom properties and delete them. However, saving the document somehow does not work.
This is the code I am using:

```
'RemoveCustomProperties.vbs
Option Explicit
dim objWord
dim WordDoc
dim CProp
dim StdOut 'Just for debugging output

set StdOut = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetStandardStream(1)

Set objWord = WScript.CreateObject("Word.Application")

objWord.Documents.Open WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
objWord.Visible = true 

for each WordDoc in objWord.Documents

  stdout.writeline "Before:"
  'go through all custom properties, list them and delete them

  for each CProp in WordDoc.CustomDocumentProperties
    stdout.writeline cprop.name & "=" & cprop.value
    CProp.delete
  next

  stdout.writeline "Afterwards:"
  'go through all custom properties again, none are there as expected
  for each CProp in WordDoc.CustomDocumentProperties
    stdout.writeline cprop.name & "=" & cprop.value
  next

next

objWord.Documents.Save
objWord.Quit

set StdOut = Nothing
Set objWord = Nothing
```

I call it from a Windows CMD using the following easy Syntax:

```
cscript <path-to-vbs>\RemoveCustomProperties.vbs <WordFile>.docm
```

The word document contains one custom property named MYPROP, value is "Mist".

The word file pops up and closes again. In the CMD window you can read:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host, Version 5.812 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Before:
MYPROP=Mist
Afterwards:
```

When I run it again on the same file, I get the same result.
The custom property is listed and deleted. However the document is apparently not saved.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't have Word installed to test, but it looks like you should doing something like WordDoc.Save or WordDoc.SaveAs inside the loop. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856856

Comment: Yes, I tried this as well with the same result. According to the Microsoft Docs, objWord.Documents.save shall save all opened documents in this session.

Comment: I'm not sure what the default is for the Document.Save "NoPrompt" parameter - but perhaps you could try setting that first optional parameter to True.